Problems with subscript operator and parameter pack expansion
When syntactically checking for subscription access by means of parameter pack expansion, I would expect the following code to work without producing any errors. However, MSVC rejects both the syntax of the constraint within the requires-clause, as well as the last assertion.
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
concept c = requires(T t, Ts... ts) {
    { t[ts...] } noexcept;             // clang ok, gcc ok, msvc nope
};

static_assert(not c<int[]>);           // all ok
static_assert(not c<int[], int, int>); // all ok
static_assert(c<int[], int>);          // clang ok, gcc ok, msvc nope

Is this simply a compiler bug of MSVC? Which rule in the C++23 standard defined this code to be legal?
Demo

MSVC's error message:
<source>(3): error C2760: syntax error: 'noexcept' was unexpected here; expected ';'
<source>(3): error C2760: syntax error: ']' was unexpected here; expected '}'
<source>(8): error C2607: static assertion failed
<source>(8): note: the concept 'c<int[],int>' evaluated to false


T{} is not valid for T=int[], are you intentionally conflating that with checking multi-dimensional indexing? Also, you're claiming MSVC is okay with the first two but your link shows that it is not.

@Barry Ah yeah, this was kinda lost in translation when creating the MRE. The original code was along the lines of requires(T&& obj, Args&&... args) {{ std::forward<T>(obj)[std::forward<Args>(args)...] } noexcept; };. I'm surprised that Clang doesn't produce a warning for essentially using a compiler-extension while having the -pedantic flag enabled. I'll change the question to focus on MSVC's unexpected behavior.
